# Rails 5.2: How do I use page specific JS scripts when using Turbolinks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I am writing some exploratory javascript for a page. It includes the following line:

```
dashboard_settings.addEventListener('ajax:complete', function(){
  ...
```

I have placed the script just before the closing body tag.

I notice that when I navigate to the page, the JS works as I expect it to and there are no error messages in the console. However, when I navigate away from the page, an error message displays in the JS console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

I understand that this is something to do with turbolinks. However, I am unsure how to go about avoiding it without turning turbolinks off.

Is there any way at all that I can specify that the script loads for the one page only?

I have tried the following without success:

```
<%= yield :page_scripts %>
<% content_for :page_scripts do %>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function(){
    ...
```

Comment: I think you should try some processing upon page load like: `$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {})`. Check the Turbolinks part from documentation: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks

Answer (score 0):

You can add the listener only if the element exists.

```
if (dashboard_settings)
  dashboard_settings.addEventListener('ajax:complete', function(){...})
```

Or, if you wan't to add it only for a specific page, you could add a yield statement on your layout and only set it's content con the desired page

```
#layout
<html>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
  <%= yield(:after_body) -%>
</html>


#your view
<%= content_for :after_body do -%>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function(){
      dashboard_settings.addEventListener('ajax:complete', function(){...})
    })
  </script>
<%- end -%>
```